# Problem with maven release:prepare for Spring Boot 2.3.1.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, git, spring-boot, maven

I have a project with the following parent:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

and the following plugins:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
                    <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

When I try to make **mvn -DpreparationGoals=clean release:prepare** it fails with this message:

```
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /root/.jenkins/workspace/Eureka-Client_Pipeline_develop && git push ssh://will:*******@github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot.git/PGXperts-Eureka-Client develop:develop
[INFO] Working directory: /root/.jenkins/workspace/Eureka-Client_Pipeline_develop
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.459s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jul 07 14:34:14 CEST 2020
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/536M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project PGXperts-Eureka-Client: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
[ERROR] Host key verification failed.
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

For the first line of the Error message I can notice that it is trying to make a push to github and not to my git repository, this step was working without problems when I was working with **spring-boot-starter-parent 2.2.7.RELEASE**. I think maybe the problem can be solved updating the version of the plugins, but I tested with versions **3.0.0-M1 for maven-release-plugin** and **1.11.2 for maven-scm-plugin** and I get the same error. Is this error because of this versions? If yes, which versions should I choose? It is maybe a bug from spring-boot-starter-parent?

Comment: What do you mean by "my repository"? A local maven repository, or the project git repository?

Comment: @George The project git repository

Comment: I don't have a solution for your problem. But the Maven release plugin is a mess. I use gitflow plugin for a long time

Comment: @SimonMartinelli you mean this? https://aleksandr-m.github.io/gitflow-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: Looks like when it is pushing it fails at getting the password. How were you authenticated before?

Comment: @George Actually if you see, it is trying to make this: git push ssh://will:*******@github.com/... but my project is not on github is in a local server, therefore the authentication is failing

Comment: Yes sthis from Aleksandr works very well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [small regression](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21989) in Spring Boot 2.3.0 and 2.3.1 that means that your project will be inheriting more from `spring-boot-starter-parent` than it should. This includes information about the project's source code management (SCM) which I suspect is why the push is being made to the wrong place.

The [Spring Boot reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-pom) shows the elements that you should override to avoid inheriting them. If you are using Spring Boot 2.3.1 or 2.3.0, there are some additional overrides that need to be made. These additions leave the complete set looking like the following:

```
<description/>
<url/>
<organization/>
<issueManagement/>
<developers>
    <developer/>
</developers>
<licenses>
    <license/>
</licenses>
<scm>
    <connection/>
    <developerConnection/>
    <url/>
</scm>
```

Adding the above, or upgrading to Spring Boot 2.3.2 when it is released, should restore Spring Boot 2.2's behavior.

Comment: Just as a note: the `scm` tag is the only thing related to git repositories.